# Slim 3 - how to use or-operator in the route?

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

How can I do 'or' in the route?

for instance, `/about` and `/fr/about` are pointing to the same objects/classes/methods. So instead of:

```
$app->get('/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});

$app->get('/{language:[fr|en]+}/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});
```

I tried with this:

```
$app->get('/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}|/{language:[fr|en]+}/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});
```

I get this error:

```
Type: FastRoute\BadRouteException
Message: Cannot use the same placeholder "url" twice
File: /var/www/mysite/vendor/nikic/fast-route/src/DataGenerator/RegexBasedAbstract.php
```

Any ideas what how to resolve this issue?

Or any solutions to avoid **repeating** the code?

Comment: the error comes from your last route pattern, you reference url twice... you need to not use the same token twice.

Comment: @geggleto any solutions to avoid repeating the code then?

Comment: To not duplicate code may look into http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#container-resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changing the order of the placeholders is possible for you, you could implement it in this manner:

```
$app->get('/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}[/{language:[en|fr]+}]', function($request, $response, $args) {
    // code here...
});
```

By "changing the order of the placeholders" I mean the url comes first, then the language, so instead of `fr/about` you use `about/fr`.

The solution utilizes [Slim's built-in optional segments](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-placeholders): note the square brackets that wrap "language" placeholder.

It, however, requires that the optional segments are placed at the end of the route, otherwise you get `FastRoute\BadRouteException`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's why what you are trying does not work.

Your Routing:

```
$app->get('/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});

$app->get('/{language:[fr|en]+}/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});
```

FastRoute finds the first match and dispatches.
If you look at this, your first route matches both `/about` and `/fr/about`
So it gets dispatched first...
In fact, it will always dispatch first, always.

What you actually want is to reorder the route definitions.

```
$app->get('/{language:[fr|en]+}/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});
// ADD OTHER ROUTES HERE

// CATCH ALL
$app->get('/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});
```

---

To solve the URL duplication problem... simply define a different token.

```
$app->get('/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}|/{language:[fr|en]+}/{url2:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    // same staff
});
```

Comment: with `'/{url:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}|/{language:[fr|en]+}/{url2:[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+}' ` I will always get a 404 page.

Comment: I'm not really a regex expert... :D What exactly are you trying to do?